# simpy resources opening time

Tags: python, resources, simpy

I would like to simulate a system where resources have an opening time during the day:

When a processes request a resource, the resource gives its availability only if there is enough time left in the day to complete the process (the process would declare how much time it needs); otherwise, the resource waits until the next day, holding the process in the queue without letting other processes to jump ahead.

I was thinking to implement a preemptive resource and a special high priority process that keeps the resource busy during the closing time. Unfortunately, if one process gets preempted, it is interrupted and gets out of the queue; thus, it seems that I cannot use preemption.

How in your opinion could be opening time simulated?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Fausto

Answer (score 0):

Using a preemptive resource was my first idea, too. If this does not work for you, you may have to subclass Resource and/or the corresponding event classes. You can use the other, more specialized Resource subclasses as an example.

Comment: Thank you, I will study the existing subclasses, and than write a specialised version that fits my needs.

Comment: It would be nice if you could share your results here, when you are done. :)